# PHP String into array keyed by word start

Tags: php

Say I have the following string

```
$str = "once in a great while a good-idea turns great";
```

What would be the best solution to creating an array with the array key being the string count of where the word(s) starts?

```
$str_array['0'] = "once";
$str_array['5'] = "in";
$str_array['8'] = "a";
$str_array['10'] = "great";
$str_array['16'] = "while";
$str_array['22'] = "a";
$str_array['24'] = "good-idea";
$str_array['34'] = "turns";
$str_array['40'] = "great";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Answer (score 10):

As simple as the following:

```
str_word_count($str, 2);
```

what `str_word_count()` does is

> [**`str_word_count()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) — Return information about words used in a string

Comment: Gotta love built-in PHP functions!  I didn't know about this one :)

Comment: I didn't know about this, but given that PHP covers every random requirement I should have just googled it.

Answer (score 7):

[str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) with 2 as the second argument to get the the offset; and you'd probably need to use the 3rd argument to include hyphen as well as letters in words

Comment: I didn't know about this function!  It's cool that there's a built-in solution!

Comment: I find  anew one in PHP almost every day ;)  Mark, good addition regarding the `charlist` argument re. the hyphen.

Comment: `str_word_count($str, 2);` reads `good-idea` as one word http://codepad.org/Hhao41Y2 :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = "once in a great while a good-idea turns great";
print_r(str_word_count($str, 2));
```

demo:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e1afc68725c1472fc595b54c5f8a8abf4620dfc

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$array = preg_split("/ /",$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$str_array = Array();
foreach($array as $word) $str_array[$word[1]] = $word[0];
```

EDIT: Just saw Mark Baker's answer. Probably a better option than mine!

Comment: I just posted this answer too, but then I saw `str_word_count`.  That's so much better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) (with the `PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option) to split the string on the space, then use the offset it gives you to make a new array.

```
$str = "once in a great while a good-idea turns great";
$split_array = preg_split('/ /', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$str_array = array();

foreach($split_array as $split){
    $str_array[$split[1]] = $split[0];
}
```